# Can I enforce the order branches are merged on GitHub

Tags: python, git, github, merge

I have a github repo that contains three protected branches; master, staging & uat. Anyone may make other branches to make changes but I would like a way make sure that people merge in this order:

users_branch -> uat -> staging -> master.

I have looked at pre-receive hooks using python but cant seem to get information I need on which branches are being merged to create this logic. The only arguments available in pre-receive are; base, commit & ref

Is there anyway to enforce that only uat may merge into staging and only staging may merge into master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a workflow with [git-flow](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/).

Or you could setup a manual process where commit rights to those branches reside with one person who is responsible for pulling in changes and merging them in the right order.

One thing to remember with Git is these controls will only apply at your 'central' repo. You can't control what happens at the individual cloned repos. Also since hooks are not distributed with repositories for security reasons, you will not be able to enforce the this order via hooks either.

Comment: git-flow was definitely a great read and helped me understand release strategies in general. However I still suffer when GitHub comes into play. However the github issues was outside the scope of this question so i posted a new one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000969/can-i-apply-the-git-flow-workflow-on-github).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best you could do is to check all merge commits in the newly pushed commits to check whether they have exactly two parents and the second parent is contained in the branch you want to enforce merging from.

But you cannot add arbitrary git hooks to GitHub repositories anyway, or can you?